# Error propagation for slope of linear regression

Tags: regression, linear, error-propagation

I want to calculate the standard deviation of the slope $k$ of

$$\ln y = kx + d$$

where the error of $y$ is assumed to be 10% and the error of $x$ is neglected. How to perform a graphical approximation is clear, but not how to calculate the impact of the standard deviation of $y$ on the std dev of $k$.

Comment: If the response variable, $\ln y$ has constant conditional (on $x$) population standard deviation $\sigma$, the standard error of slope of a linear regression will be proportional to that $\sigma$.